# Vagrant/Redis - Cannot connect from host

Tags: redis, vagrant

Still getting the hang of Vagrant/Redis/Linux. Please help! The issue is I cannot connect to redis server running on VM.

**Host: Macbook**

**Vagrantfile:**

```
config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
config.vm.hostname="redis-test"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6379, id: "redis"
```

---

**Guest: laravel/homestead Vagrant box.**

**/etc/redis/redis.conf**

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

After changing redis.conf, I also restarted the service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server restart
(AND also) sudo service redis-server restart
```

Also made sure ufw is disabled

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw status
```

> Status: inactive

If I run `redis-cli -h redis-test ping`, I get `pong`, and can access redis as usual (on the guest VM)

---

Now back on the host machine (macbook), I cannot access redis-server.

```
redis-cli -h redis-test ping
```

> Could not connect to Redis at redis-test:6379: nodename nor servname
>   provided, or not known

Can someone help me connect to redis-server on vagrant box, please? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forwarded redis port 6379 from host machine to `redis-test` VM, but host machine knows nothing about `redis-test` domain you are trying to connect to.

You can connect redis on `redis-test` VM from host machine in two ways:

**1.**

connect to `localhost`, because redis port is already forwarded to redis on `redis-test` VM:

```
redis-cli -h localhost ping
```

**2.**

add `redis-test` to `/etc/hosts`:

```
echo '127.0.0.1 redis-test' >> /etc/hosts
```

and you can connect redis the way you used:

```
redis-cli -h redis-test ping
```

Comment: lol The answer was right in front of me. I had another port forward set for nginx which I was already accessing thru localhost, don't know why I didn't thought of accessing redis-cli -h localhost. Thank you very much for your help, I am able to connect now!!